# In Lua 5.3 the hyperbolic functions are deprecated, so should I use them directly or rewrite them?

Tags: math, lua

I have created a scientific calculator for the command line, and I was wondering about adding hyperbolic functions (math.tanh, math.cosh, math.sinh), these functions have been deprecated but are still available through a compatibility option that is activated by default. Should I reimplement these functions, or use them directly?

Comment: Why reimplementing them when they are implemented?

Comment: Is it possible for them to be removed from a future version if they are deprecated?

Comment: Get [lmathx](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#lmathx).

Comment: @eyescienceinternational - Probably, they will be included in Lua 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reimplement the functions. Here is an example of a reimplementation:

> http://lua-users.org/wiki/HyperbolicFunctions

```
function M.sinh (x)
  if x == 0 then return 0.0 end
  local neg = false
  if x < 0 then x = -x; neg = true end
  if x < 1.0 then
    local y = x * x
    x = x + x * y *
        (((-0.78966127417357099479e0  * y +
           -0.16375798202630751372e3) * y +
           -0.11563521196851768270e5) * y +
           -0.35181283430177117881e6) /
        ((( 0.10000000000000000000e1  * y +
           -0.27773523119650701667e3) * y +
            0.36162723109421836460e5) * y +
           -0.21108770058106271242e7)
  else
    x =  exp(x)
    x = x / 2.0 - 0.5 / x
  end
  if neg then x = -x end
  return x
end
```

Please note the following which is stated on the web page

> Preliminary tests show them(the functions) to produce results that differ at most by one bit when compared to the libC implementations.

Comment: Note, though, that implementing any kind of special function _well_ is _stupidly_ tricky, enough for a couple of years of mathematical articles (see _e.g._ the CR-libm report https://hal.inria.fr/ensl-01529804/). And downright impossible to do unless you know what `LUA_NUMBER` is. No idea why Lua is removing mathematical functions when C is adding them.